# can Ruby (or Rails) class loses its object_id during single thread execution?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've spotted strange bug.

When running a db:seed script in my Ubuntu Laptop MRI 2.6.3 Ruby everything goes well.

But when I trigger same db:seed script under Docker container (MRI 2.6.3, Rails 5.2.3) it seems one particular class loses its object ID:

```
[47] pry(#<Maintenance::SeedDataService>)> school
=> #<School id:1 public_uid:4ca01880 title:Dummy School>
[48] pry(#<Maintenance::SeedDataService>)> school.class
=> School(id: integer, title: string, .......)
[49] pry(#<Maintenance::SeedDataService>)> school.class.object_id
=> 70060822718420
[50] pry(#<Maintenance::SeedDataService>)> 
[51] pry(#<Maintenance::SeedDataService>)> 
[52] pry(#<Maintenance::SeedDataService>)> School.object_id
=> 70060817034380
[53] pry(#<Maintenance::SeedDataService>)> school.class == School
=> false
[54] pry(#<Maintenance::SeedDataService>)>
```

So basically `school = School.last; school.class != School`

or other words `School != School`

I've triple checked there is no other definitions of `class School` in code base or related Gems

Script is executed in single thread (as `rake db:seed` and nothing is reloading any classes. So best to my knowledge Ruby class object should never lose its id (as it's acting as Singleton)

this is like if `1` loses its object id and suddenly `1 != 1`

Am I missing somethnig here or this is a Ruby bug  inside Docker container ?

Comment: I bet on nested constant resolution gotcha. Do you have `Maintenance::School` or `Maintenance::SeedDataService::School`?

Comment: yeah someone edited my question wrong way

Comment: ah ok my bad my bad, Rails 5.2.3 :) sorry My mistake

Comment: Re: nested constant resolution :  That's the thing I've triple checked it there is no such definition (4th time I've checked after you posted the question :) )   There is no such thing as `Maintenance::School` or anything like it ...and worst thing is that outside Docker container this works, only inside Docker container :(

Comment: That's weird. I'll need a repro to proceed any further, I think.

Comment: it's company project so I cannot share it, :( I'll try my best to investigate. I just wanted to confirm I'm not loosing any point. (E.g. object lifecyle in Ruby I'm not aware of) , but still thank you for trying to help

Comment: Yes, as far as I'm aware, a class should not change its object_id in the middle of program execution.

Comment: just for giggles can you try `school.class == ::School`

Comment: `School == ::School` 
resulted true
`school.class == ::School` resulted false   ...only in Docker not in Laptop

Comment: @equivalent8 just for debugging, what happens if you wrap everything in a loop or copy paste your code 3 times, do the object ids change? for both `School.object_id` and `school.class.object_id`? or only one of them? or they don't change after the first iteration?